# Javascript Obfuscator

Tags: javascript

Давно интересует вопрос, но времени не хватало на обсуждение.

Я функцию:

```
function $(id) { return document.getElementById(id); }
```

Обработал с помощью обфускатора и получил в итоге:

```
eval(function(p,a,c,k,e,d){e=function(c){return c};if(!''.replace(/^/,String)){while(c--){d[c]=k[c]||c}k=[function(e){return d[e]}];e=function(){return'\\w+'};c=1};while(c--){if(k[c]){p=p.replace(new RegExp('\\b'+e(c)+'\\b','g'),k[c])}}return p}('1 $(0){2 3.4(0)}',5,5,'id|function|return|document|getElementById'.split('|'),0,{}))
```

Назрел вопрос, где можно найти достаточно достнойной информации, с подробным описанием заветного обработчика

```
('1 $(0){2 3.4(0)}',5,5,'id|function|return|document|getElementById'.split('|'),0,{}))
```

Значение количества цифр, точек, запятых, слешей и т.д. И реально ли внося изменения в этот обработчик скосить массу скриптов для обращения хотя бы к DOM элементам. Спасибо.

З.Ы. Обфускацию делал тут [Daft Logic](http://www.daftlogic.com/projects-online-javascript-obfuscator.htm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скосить в размере - реально. Хотя тут вопрос каждого конкретного случая в отдельности. Загвоздка будет в другом: eval будет тормозить работу браузера при открытии странички (несильно, но будет). Ради интереса, обфусцируйте js-код Хэшкода и замерьте.